# Mathematical notation for R::tail(X, n = 1)

Tags: r, notation

Given a *sorted* vector $X$, the minimum is expressed symbolically as $X_{(1)}$ and the maximum as $X_{(n)}$.

Supposing for a given *unsorted* vector $Y$, we wanted to know the last value in said vector, we could achieve this through typing in R:

```
tail(Y, n = 1)
```

**My question is**: Is there more concise mathematical notation for this?

Clearly, if $Y$ were sorted, then the tail would correspond to the maximum.

It seems that there should be a shorthand way to express this, but I've come up with little in terms of an direct answer.

Comment: I wonder if you can get away with denoting it $y_{n}$ or just saying "last component/member of vector $Y$". Because usually vector and its members can be written $Y=[y_1,y_2,...,y_{n-1},y_n]^T$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this related post on Mathematics SE, which sufficiency answers my question. I just had to alter things a bit according to my specifications.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844748/notation-for-matrix-and-sum-of-matrix-rows